# With an exclusive Company Calendar do Dax calculation YTD same time in previous years and MTD

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'd appreciate some assistance.
I'm interested in performing YTD same time in previous years, and MTD DAX computations, I have a table of "Sales Order and Invoice" and a "Date Invoice"

I have a Date field in my dimension "Date Invoice" that is ideal for this kind of calculation, but the company has a proper calendar, as you can see below an example normally the beginning and end of the months belong to different months.

[image: 1 and 2 of July belongs to month 6 June]

[image: 31 of July belongs to month 8 August]

[image: PBI Model]

I'm wondering how to calculate this with the available Company fields since I can't utilise the date field.

Do you have any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'd check on DAXpatterns.com for the date-related measures. But you can do something like

```
CALCULATE([Measure],
    FILTER('DimDate',
        [DayNumberOfYear]=MAX([DayNumberOfYear]) && [CalendarYear]=MAX([CalendarYear])-1)
```

you use the Calendar table, and you get to it by joining the fact table to it. Then basically, you're just date-shifting the dates in your evaluation context backward (in your case) and align any way you want. (like by using WeekNumber and then shifting the year backward). In a word, you use FILTER and standard date functions.